# Set UITextField delegate to all UITextFields and set view animation for few textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have 13 text fields. I want to set view animation for only 4 text fields which will be displayed in bottom

**Here is my code:**

```
if (textField.editing != ((_GET_companyname)||(_GET_firstname)||(_GET_middlename)||(_GET_lastname)||(_GET_companyurl)||(_GET_streetaddress)||(_GET_postbox)||(_GET_code)||(_GET_phonenum)))
{
    NSLog(@"Entered in condition");
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //Keyboard becomes visible
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        // [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Entered else Part");
}
```

I need to set the below to all 14 textfields

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: what is _GET_companyname and others?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I have 13 Text fields I want to set text view deligate to all and set Uiview animation to 4 text fields @Andy

Comment: _GET_ etc are the text fields in the view controller @Kiran

Comment: then why are you checking (textField.editing)? instead you should check (textfield) only

Comment: @Jayasabeen if you use IB to create those text fields then you can create IBOutletCollection property and assign a collection of fields that you want to manipulate. Then you can loop through them and animate them.

Comment: I get Warning like this Comparison between pointer and integer ('UITextField *' and 'int') @Kiran

Comment: I am not aware of IBOutletCollection I will try this great thanks @Andy

Comment: @Jayasabeen take a look at http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/#iboutletcollection

Comment: @Jayasabeen Please correct the spelling of Delegate

Comment: Unable to edit @AshokLondhe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check these using tags 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
UITextField *textFiledName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
textFiledName.tag = 0;
textFiledName.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textFiledName];

UITextField *textFiledLastName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
textFiledLastName.tag = 1;
textFiledLastName.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textFiledLastName];
```

}

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField.tag == 0) {
  //No Animation
}else  if (textField.tag == 1){
   //Add Animation
}
return YES;
```

}

Comment: finally worked if (textField.tag > 8)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        // [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

Answer (score 1):

According to you if "_GET_companyname" is a IBOutlet of UITextField.

Then you should write something like this below

```
if ((textField != _GET_companyname)&&(textField != _GET_firstname)) // etc
{
    NSLog(@"Entered in condition");
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //Keyboard becomes visible
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        // [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Entered else Part");
}
```

Edit :- And also instead of checking (!=). you should check (==) for few UITextFields. That will be better.

Comment: Always enters if block even if i perform a action to be executed in else part

Comment: you have to update this code according to your needs and i also edited it and added (&&) condition in between